# .serializer encodes cdata

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

We've built an object model from an xml schema.  We then use serialization to go from xml to objects and objects to xml.  If we start with xml that contains CDATA in one of the elements, it deserializes to the object fine, but serializing it back to xml causes the CDATA to get lost and the contents to be Xml encoded.  Is there a way to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: html encoded? are you sure you don't mean xml-encoded? Either way, CDATA and xml-encoded are both valid ways of representing the same data

Comment: @Marc Gravell, You are right, sorry that was a typo.